# Why does using a ConditionalAccessExpression change how my extension method works?

Tags: c#, compiler-errors, extension-methods

I have an extension method that looks like this:

```
public static bool DoesNotExist(this object toCheck)
{
  return toCheck == null;
}
```

generally I use it like this:

```
if(myObject.DoesNotExist())
{
}
```

I have an expression which contains a conditional access expression like this

```
if (myObject?.MyProperty == null)
```

which the compiler is happy with. If I that expression to use my extension method, like this:

```
if (myObject?.MyProperty.DoesNotExist())
```

then I get a compiler error

> CS0266 Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool?' to 'bool'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

The type of MyProperty is some object from my domain, not a bool.

Why does this happen, and can I prevent it?

Comment: `if ((myObject?.MyProperty).DoesNotExist())` does seem to work though

Comment: @haim770that is interesting. Thanks for that, I might be able to use that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A null conditional expression always has a nullable return type - after all, it has to have an overall result of `null` if the left hand side is null.

So the type of `myObject?.MyProperty.DoesNotExist()` is `Nullable<bool>`, which can't be used as the condition for an `if` statement.

It's easy to fix either by direct comparison with a `bool` constant, or using the null coalescing operator:

```
if (myObject?.MyProperty.DoesNotExist() == true)

if (myObject?.MyProperty.DoesNotExist() ?? false)
```

In both of those cases, if `myObject` is null, execution won't enter the body of the `if` statement. If you want the opposite behaviour, you can use:

```
if (myObject?.MyProperty.DoesNotExist() != false)

if (myObject?.MyProperty.DoesNotExist() ?? true)
```

However, I'm not sure that your extension method is actually a useful one - at least not here. If you're just doing a null comparison, do that directly:

```
if (myObject?.MyProperty == null)
```

That will go into the body of the `if` statement if *either* `myObject` is null, *or* `myObject.MyProperty` is null.

Comment: Thanks. The issue came up as I'm writing a roslyn analyzer which offers to change `==null` to use `DoesNotExist`, and have removed the offer of an automatic fix for expressions which contain a conditional access expression, which seems like the sensible thing to do here.

Comment: @SamHolder: Right, in that case you probably want the `?? true` version. Although personally I'd discourage this anyway, as I think it's easier to under the `== null` version...

Comment: yeah, I'm going to stick with the `==null` version in this situation I think, unless I surround the whole expression in an additional set of brackets as `(myObject?.MyProperty).DoesNotExist()` works ok as @haim770 pointed out in the comments on the question. Probably just stick with checking for null though